# Shorthand for creating indexes on all columns

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In Doctrine2, I can write the following if I want to create single-column indexes for a set of columns in an entity:

```
/**
 * Project
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Company\SomeBundle\Entity\ProjectRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(indexes={
 * @ORM\Index(name="name_idx", columns={"name"}),
 * @ORM\Index(name="started_idx", columns={"started"}),
 * })
 */
```

However, what if I wanted to create an index for each column in this entity? Is there a shorthand for this, so that I don't have to write it explicitly for each column like in the above example?

Comment: Creating index on every column is *very bad idea*. You should only create indexes that are needed - maintaining indexes is expensive both computationally and in terms of storage space. Most of your one-column indexes are never going to be used anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just list properties that should be indexed.

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="ecommerce_products",indexes={@index(name="search_idx",columns={"name","email"})})
 */
 class ECommerceProduct
 {
 }
```

Comment: Won't this create a single index over multiple columns though, as opposed to a single index per column?

Comment: It creates single index over multiple columns.

Comment: It was not exactly what I asked for, but with the technical implications in mind I accept this answer since it addresses my original problem better than the original way I intended to address it.